# Analytical integration of product of exponential functions

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I am trying to obtain an **analytical formula for the following integral**. My first question is whether it is possible to obtain an analytical formula without the use of transcendental functions. My second question is to ask whether anybody has any idea how to calculate this integral. Many thanks for any pointers you may have.
$$
\int_{0}^{t}{\left\{ \sum\limits_{i=0}^{mMax}{{{A}_{i}}\,}{{e}^{-\xi /{{B}_{i}}}}\left[ \frac{\text{ }{{\text{e}}^{-2k\left( -\xi -T/2 \right)}}}{{{\left( 1+{{\text{e}}^{-2k\left( -\xi -T/2 \right)}} \right)}^{2}}}-\underset{n=1}{\overset{nMax}{\mathop \sum }}\,2{{\left( -1 \right)}^{n}}\frac{\,{{\text{e}}^{-2k\left( \xi -nT \right)}}}{{{\left( 1+{{\text{e}}^{-2k\left( \xi -nT \right)}} \right)}^{2}}} \right] \right\}\,d\xi }
$$

Comment: are you sure about the positions of your brackets?

Comment: Yes, the position of brackets is correct

Comment: Forgot to say that the terms between brackets is the derivative of a differentiable approximation of the periodic Heaviside function of period 2T. The larger the k the better the approximation.